# Object Math.max and indexof to get the index

Tags: jquery, object, indexof, howler.js

I have the following object:

```
var thisArray = {
   user1: sounduser1,
   user2: sounduser2
};
```

`sounduser1` and `sounduser2` are audiofiles played through howler.js (great script!)

Using `._duration` you'll get a number - the length of the audio.

I wanted to get the longest audio, which I did get through:

```
var audiogetlength = Object.keys( thisArray ).map(function ( key ) { 
                        return thisArray[key]._duration;
                     });
var longest = Math.max.apply( null, audiogetlength );
```

What I would like is the original [key] (or index?) of the longest audiofile: `var longest`

So I tried `indexOf`

```
var thisone = longest.indexOf(longest ));
```

But it doesn't seem to be logical… and it doesn't work…

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with a good old `for` loop?

```
var keys = Object.keys( thisArray ),
    maxDuration = 0,
    maxKey;
for( var i=keys.length; i--; ) {
  if( thisArray[ keys[i] ]._duration > maxDuration ) {
    maxKey = keys[i];
    maxDuration = thisArray[ keys[i] ]._duration;
  }
}

// maximum (longeste) length in maxDuration
// respective key in maxKey
```

Comment: I don't seem to get a number out of maxDuration. Will maxDuration be the longest of those two?

Comment: @Joep If the property `_duration` contains a number, this should return the largest one. You sure about that being a number?

Comment: It worked, thanks! A lost 'ü' made the code return nothing. I changed the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just getting the length from the object properties you can get the key and the length. If you sort the array descending on the length, you can get the length and key from the first item:

```
var audiogetlength = Object.keys( thisArray ).map(function ( key ) {
  return { key: key, len: thisArray[key]._duration };
});
audiogetlength.sort(function(a, b){ return b.len - a.len; });
var longest = audiogetlength[0].len;
var key = audiogetlength[0].key;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will work on it. It doesn't seem to work yet.